# How to re-size absolute positioned images with CSS?

Tags: css, image, mobile, resize

How do you get CSS to scale down two absolute positioned images, side-by-side, within their own div but inside a parent wrapper?

I have looked at many stackoverflow questions, but could not find an answer for how to deal with two or more images. I have tried multiple CSS examples but to no avail.

I put together a mock example that simulates what I’m trying to do. See http://www.netplayhockey.com/test.php. Please note that there is a reason the images are different widths and in their own div (has to do with some absolute text positioning that I removed for this demo).

The page width is 1024px (image1 598px, image2 426px). If you reduce the width of the browser, I would like both images to scale down. But, instead, the images do not change size. In fact, image2 overlaps image1.

It’s doing what I want when browser width is less than 600px (I picked 600px as an example, I really want this to occur for mobile but not iPad), I want image2 to move under image1. And the images to be centered.

Note: If I use relative positioning and float, I don't get the desired centering results (the images stack when screen is less than 1024px, and they don't center).

Attached is the HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-left"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
            <div class="footer-right"><img src="image2.png" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    position:relative;
    background:#999; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    max-width:1024px;           
    margin:0 auto;
}
.footer-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.footer {               
    position:relative;
}
.footer-left {      
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
.footer-right {     
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
.footer img {
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
}
@media all and (max-width:600px) {  
    .footer-left {  
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .footer-right {
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Thank you! I slightly modified the CSS (removed some stuff that wasn't needed for it to work like I want it). - I had to re-edit, to show CSS code. after I posted my thank you

```
  .footer {             
        position:relative;
    }
    .footer-left {      
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:58.4%;
    }
    .footer-right {     
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        width:41.6%;
    }
    .footer img {
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    @media all and (max-width:600px) {  
        .footer-left, .footer-right {   
            position:relative;
            float:none;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            text-align:center;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

will this work for you ?

http://jsfiddle.net/PR4DE/btzj5dtu/

for future reference:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1"><img src="http://www.netplayhockey.com/image1.png"></div>
    <div class="col-2"><img src="http://www.netplayhockey.com/image2.png"></div>
</div>

/*style*/
.grid {position:relative;max-width:960px;margin:0 auto;}
.col-1 {position:relative;width:58.4%;float:left;}
.col-2 {position:relative;width:41.6%;float:left;}


@media (max-width:960px) {
.col-1 {width:100%;float:none;height:auto;}
.col-2 {width:100%;float:none;height:auto;}
img {width:100%;height:auto;}
}
```

Comment: Awesome :) glad i could help.
- Will you make this, as the answer?